# How to merge 2 Enumerators in one, based on merge rule

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, enumerator, loops

We have a small Scala project on Playframework. I'm trying to do everything reactive, and stumbled on a problem.

I have two Enumerator[A] instances, representing values from a DB ordered by date.
I need to return them as a single Enumerator[A] keeping date ordering. I have not found any solution for that in Enumerator[A], so I'm accumulating A's in single collection, and ordering them afterwards.

```
case class A(
   created: Date,
   data: String
)

val as: Enumerator[A] = findByAOrderedByCreated()
val bs: Enumerator[A] = findByBOrderedByCreated()
```

**What is reactive way to deal with this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that will work for any number of `Enumerator` values using any `Ordering` on the elements:

```
import play.api.libs.iteratee._
import scala.concurrent._

object MergeEnums {
  def apply[E: Ordering](enums: Enumerator[E]*)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext) = new Enumerator[E] {
    def apply[A](iter: Iteratee[E, A]) = {
      case class IterateeReturn(o: Option[(Promise[Promise[IterateeReturn]], E)])

      val failP = Promise()
      val failPF = failP.future
      val initState = Future.traverse(enums) { enum =>
        val p = Promise[IterateeReturn]()
        enum.run(Iteratee.foldM(p) { (oldP: Promise[IterateeReturn], elem: E) =>
          val p = Promise[Promise[IterateeReturn]]()
          oldP success IterateeReturn(Some(p, elem))
          p.future
        } map { promise =>
          promise success IterateeReturn(None)
        }) onFailure { case t => failP failure t }
        p.future
      } map (_.map(_.o).flatten.toList)

      Enumerator.unfoldM(initState) { fstate =>
        Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(fstate, failPF)) map { state =>
          state.sortBy(_._2) match {
            case Nil => None
            case (oldP, elem) :: tail =>
              val p = Promise[IterateeReturn]()
              oldP success p
              val newState = p.future.map(_.o.map(_ :: tail).getOrElse(tail))
              Some(newState, elem)
          }
        }
      } apply iter
    }
  }
}
```

It creates an `Iteratee` to apply to each `Enumerator` that is passed in, and an `Enumerator` to give the sorted elements. The `Iteratee` instances and the `Enumerator` communicate by sending `Promise` instances to each other (hence the `Promise[Promise[IterateeReturn]]` and such).

Comment: Thanks :) That means a lot coming from the Play tech lead.

Comment: Sorry, it took me allot of time to finally start using it

Comment: We have used wingedsubmariner's code above in production for a while and would recommend against it. It seems to contain a memory leak causing our application to run out of memory when used with long Enumerators. Since nobody in our team was able to understand it, we couldn't debug it either.