# Find difference between two enumerators with sorted entries in scala

Tags: scala, playframework, enumerator, loops

Given two scala play enumerators A and B that each provide **sorted** integers, is there a way to derive an enumerator of integers that exist in B that don't exist in A?

For example:

```
val A: Enumerator[Int] = Enumerator(1,3,5,9,11,13)
```

and

```
val B: Enumerator[Int] = Enumerator(1,3,5,7,9,11,13)
```

I would somehow get:

```
val C: Enumerator[Int] // This enumerator will output 7
```

Doing it in a reactive way with enumerators/iteratees/enumeratees is preferred.

One solution I've thought of is to interleave the enumerators and somehow use Iteratee.fold to maintain a buffer to compare the two streams but that seems like it should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had somewhat similar question
[How to merge 2 Enumerators in one, based on merge rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110082/how-to-merge-2-enumerators-in-one-based-on-merge-rule)
I modified given answer, to fit your needs

```
object Disjunction {

    def disjunction[E: Ordering](enumA: Enumerator[E], enumB: Enumerator[E])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = new Enumerator[E] {

        def apply[A](iter: Iteratee[E, A]) = {
            case class IterateeReturn(o: Option[(Promise[Promise[IterateeReturn]], E)])

            val failP: Promise[Nothing] = Promise() // Fail promise
            val failPF: Future[Nothing] = failP.future // Fail promise future

            val initState1: Future[Seq[IterateeReturn]] = Future.traverse(Seq(enumA, enumB)) {
                enum =>
                    val p: Promise[IterateeReturn] = Promise[IterateeReturn]()

                    // The flow to transform Enumerator in IterateeReturn form
                    enum.run(Iteratee.foldM(p)({
                        (oldP: Promise[IterateeReturn], elem: E) =>
                            val p = Promise[Promise[IterateeReturn]]()
                            // Return IterateeReturn pointing to the next foldM Future reference, and current element
                            oldP success IterateeReturn(Some(p, elem))
                            // Return new Future as a Result of foldM
                            p.future
                        }) map ({
                            promise => promise success IterateeReturn(None) // Finish last promise with empty IterateeReturn
                        })
                    ) onFailure {
                        // In case of failure main flow needs to be informed
                        case t => failP failure t
                    }

                    p.future
            }

            val initState: Future[List[(Promise[Promise[IterateeReturn]], E)]] = initState1 map (_.map(_.o).flatten.toList)

            val newEnum: Enumerator[Option[E]] = Enumerator.unfoldM(initState) { fstate =>
                // Whatever happens first, fstate returned of failure happened during iteration
                Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(fstate, failPF)) map { state =>
                    // state is List[(Promise[Promise[IterateeReturn]], E)
                    // sort elements by E
                    if (state.isEmpty) {
                        None
                    } else if (state.length == 1) {
                        val (oldP, elem) = state.head
                        val p = Promise[IterateeReturn]()
                        oldP success p
                        // Return newState, with this iterator moved
                        val newState: Future[List[(Promise[Promise[IterateeReturn]], E)]] = p.future.map(ir => ir.o.map(List(_)).getOrElse(Nil))
                        Some(newState, Some(elem))
                    } else {
                        val sorted = state.sortBy(_._2)
                        val (firstP, fe) = sorted.head
                        val (secondP, se) = sorted.tail.head
                        if (fe != se) {
                            // Move first and combine with the second
                            val p = Promise[IterateeReturn]()
                            firstP success p
                            val newState: Future[List[(Promise[Promise[IterateeReturn]], E)]] = p.future.map(ir => ir.o.map(List(_, (secondP, se))).getOrElse(List((secondP, se))))
                            // Return new state
                            Some(newState, Some(fe))
                        } else {
                            // Move future 1
                            val p1 = Promise[IterateeReturn]()
                            firstP success p1
                            val fState: Future[Option[(Promise[Promise[IterateeReturn]], E)]] = p1.future.map(ir => ir.o)
                            // Move future 2
                            val p2 = Promise[IterateeReturn]()
                            secondP success p2
                            val sState: Future[Option[(Promise[Promise[IterateeReturn]], E)]] = p2.future.map(ir => ir.o)
                            // Combine in new state
                            val newState = Future.sequence(List(fState, sState)).map(_.flatten)
                            // Return
                            Some(newState , None)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            newEnum &>
                Enumeratee.filter(_.isDefined) &>
                Enumeratee.map(_.get) apply iter
        }

    }

}
```

I checked, it works.

Comment: Wow.. that's... way more complicated than I thought it would be. But it certainly works.